# How can I achieve auto column in GridView flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

How do I achieve this, knowing that items might grow in number as well as in content size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `Wrap` widget easily https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
  runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
  children: <Widget>[
      Chip(
        label: Text('Mobiles'),
      ),
      Chip(
        label: Text('Tabletes'),
      ),
      Chip(
        label: Text('Vip Phone Number'),
      ),
      Chip(
        label: Text('Mobile - Tablet Spare Parts'),
      ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: I was too focused on Listview/Gridview, couldn't think of simply wrapping widgets in Wrap widget, thanks

Comment: This is amazing